# Opening data connection

Tags: c#, database, connection

In c#.net when you open a connection to a database, in my case it's oracle, is there a lot of overhead involved? I'm guessing there isn't because of connection pooling. So am I correct in saying that everytime I open a connection it actually grabs an open connection out of the pool and if there are no available connections in the pool it will then open a new connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. There are a lot of good articles explaining ADO connection pooling. For exmaple, [MSDN - SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), which says:

> Connection pooling reduces the number
>   of times that new connections must be
>   opened. The pooler maintains ownership
>   of the physical connection. It manages
>   connections by keeping alive a set of
>   active connections for each given
>   connection configuration. Whenever a
>   user calls Open on a connection, the
>   pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled
>   connection is available, it returns it
>   to the caller instead of opening a new
>   connection. When the application calls
>   Close on the connection, the pooler
>   returns it to the pooled set of active
>   connections instead of closing it.
>   Once the connection is returned to the
>   pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything else going on.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you open the connection there will be a lot of overhead.  If you are using connection pooling and you use the exact **same connection string**, the next time you open the connection it should use a connection from the connection pool and be a lot quicker.